# How can I use nested IF and OR functions to solve this equation?

Tags: excel

I am trying to get cell `A19` to calculate the formula shown below if either cell `SHARES LOG` `I2` or `SPREADS LOG` `F2` have data within. If there is no data in either of these cells I would like `A19` to return a blank cell.

Currently, the formula is calculating the formula correctly if one or both of the previously mentioned cells have data within, however, if there is no data in either cell `SHARES LOG` `I2` or `SPREADS LOG` `F2`, cell `A19` does not return a blank.

I cannot figure out why this is as the formula appears correct.

When there is no data in either `SHARES LOG` `I2` or `SPREADS LOG` `F2` the result in cell `A19` is `+ £ 0.00 / + £ 0.00`

This is the current formula in cell `A19` :

`=IF(OR(COUNT('SHARES LOG'!I2=1),('SPREADS LOG'!F2=1)),TEXT(SUM('SHARES LOG'!N:N,'SPREADS LOG'!M:M)," + £ #,##0.00")&" / "&TEXT(SUM('SHARES LOG'!L:L,'SPREADS LOG'!K:K)," + £ #,##0.00"),"")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct formula should be:

```
=IF(OR(COUNT('SHARES LOG'!I2)=1,count('SPREADS LOG'!F2)=1),TEXT(SUM('SHARES LOG'!N:N,'SPREADS LOG'!M:M)," + £ #,##0.00")&" / "&TEXT(SUM('SHARES LOG'!L:L,'SPREADS LOG'!K:K)," + £ #,##0.00"),"")
```

You have put the '=1' inside the Count so that it compares the cell 'SHARES LOG'!I2 or 'SPREADS LOG'!F2 to 1, then counts the result. The result can only be True or False, and Count will treat either of these as a number so you will always get a count of 1, meaning that your Or statement will always be satisfied and you will get a formatted number instead of a blank from the If statement.

There are other more direct ways of testing the contents of 'SHARES LOG'!I2 and 'SPREADS LOG'!F2 like using Isnumber (assuming they should contain a number).

Answer (score 1):

Although an answer already is given by [Tom Sharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3894917/tom-sharpe), I believe a better solution is formula auditing, explained in [this URL](https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/formula-auditing.html). More exactly, the "Evaluate Formula" feature is exactly what you need to solve this kind of problems: it allows you to evaluate your formula, step by step. So, you write your formula, and you try to predict what the outcome of the next step will be. At the moment your expectations don't match with the result, you have found the error in your formula.